# Can a webpage, hosted by tomcat, websocket connect over port 80 to an erlang server on the same machine as tomcat?

Tags: http, tomcat, erlang, websocket

I would like to use tomcat to serve a web page.  The webpage will make a connection using websockets over port 80.  Does this mean I need a java servlet (hosted by tomcat) to listen for a websocket connection?  Or can I use some other application to say written in erlang to listen for the websocket connections.

I'm confused about whether if I use tomcat to serve the webpage, I'm also forced to use it to listen for websockets over port 80.  I would have tomcat and the erlang app on the same machine.

Comment: What is the conclusion?; can't we support both websocket listener and HTML page servlet container on the same port 80?

Answer (score 1):

The WebSocket server could be listening on some other port than the one used to serve your HTML page (80 presumably) and might even be on a separate domain/server. As long as it respects [the specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-09), you could use any language/framework to write a WebSocket server.

Comment: The web page would be served on port 80.  I want to use port 80 for the websocket so there aren't issues with firewalls.  I didn't know about the separate server part that is good to know :)

Comment: @Xavier, yes 80 is the preferred port to avoid any potential firewall issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues of Cross Domain scripting which is usually blocked by Web Clients. However, i ask my self, why don't you let your favorite Erlang web server like Yaws or Mochiweb serve that very page from which web socket requests will be initiated?

On the same server, you can have both Tomcat and another Web server running. You can let Tomcat be on Port 80, while the other Erlang web server on say port 8080. Let the page that points to your web sockets page have the link as say: `<a href="http://Your_Domain:8080">Click here to start web sockets application</a>`

You can as well do port forwarding and stuff like that on your Server room firewall (router) to map requests incoming on one port to another